# Use python to compute long sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, sequence

Guys i'm trying to solve this equation using python

[image: Equation]

What we need to find is a value N for which that equation give a result of 2.718. 
What i did until now, having problems with decimals, is this:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal
import scipy.misc

limit = 2.718
ris = 0
n = 1
while ris <= limit:
   ris = Decimal(n / math.pow(scipy.misc.factorial(n), 1/n))
   n= n + 1

   print(n,ris)
```

The main problem is that in a certain point it start just to print Zeros and i don't know if it is still computing but not showing anymore the results or it has crashed.

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: `scipy.misc.factorial(171)` is infinity, so `n/scipy.misc.factorial(171)` is zero. Maybe you can use a different factorial function to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is using the power operator ** which is a bit faster than pow because it don't have the overhead of a function load and call.

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal

limit = Decimal(2.718)

result = 0
n = Decimal(1)
one = Decimal(1)
n_factor = Decimal(n)

while result <= limit:
    result = n / Decimal(n_factor ** (one/n))
    n += 1
    n_factor *= n
    # print (n, result) # uncomment to see intermediate results

print ('Final', n, result)
```

note: it's not optimal, but at least it will calculate the N

note #2: see comments below for explanations about the problems regarding 'scipy' and Zeros

Comment: Not the  `math.pow` is the problem, but the `scipy.misc.factorial` which will return `array(inf)` for 171.

Comment: Whoever voted down, please explain. The code I wrote will give you the answer even though it's not using 'scipy' library.

Comment: @syntonym: Tim's solution will work, your suggestion will not. While `scipy.misc.factorial` is *a* problem, it's not the *only* problem. If you substitute a function that gives the correct factorial as an integer, you'll just get an error on the pow calculation when it tries to convert it to float and it overflows; `math.pow` (and `**` with a float exponent) is part of the problem. That said, you're totally right about Tim's explanation being wrong - the problem isn't the exponent getting too small, but the base getting too big. Either way, using `Decimal` solves the problem.

Comment: @AleksiTorhamo: thank you for pointing out my mistake about `math.pow`

Answer (score 3):

Interesting answers from Tim Rijavec and syntonym. Here's some further thought.

As syntonym suggested, the problem is, for `n = 171` `scipy.misc.factorial` returns `array(inf)`. It is because when you invoke this function without additional parameters it returns a float. You could set it so that it returns the exact integer value:

```
>>> scipy.misc.factorial(171)
array(inf)
>>> scipy.misc.factorial(171, exact = True)
1241018070217667823424840524103103992616605577501693185388951803611996075221691752992751978120487585576464959501670387052809889858690710767331242032218484364310473577889968548278290754541561964852153468318044293239598173696899657235903947616152278558180061176365108428800000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>>
```

So if you rewrite the program thusly, you wouldn't get an error:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import scipy.misc

limit = Decimal(2.718)

ris = 0
n = 1
one = Decimal(1)

while ris <= limit:
   ris = n / Decimal(scipy.misc.factorial(n, exact= True) ** (one/n))
   n= n + 1

   print(n,ris)
```

But for some reason, it is inefficient and takes quite some time to finish. In situations like this you might wanna ease up on the condition:

```
while abs(ris - limit) > 0.025:
   ris = n / Decimal(scipy.misc.factorial(n, exact= True) ** (one/n))
   n= n + 1
```

Comment: It's probably slow because of the calculation of the factorial. Tims answer only multiplies once per iteration, while in your answer the factorial has to be computed each time from the ground up.